# Populate multiple select based on choices in other multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, multiple-select

Okay, I'll do my best to explain this. I have a list of company departments that are shown in a multiple select element. Each employee can be connected to several of these departments.
I get this data from our database. When I select one of the departments the list of employees in that department are shown in another multiple select element. When I select more than one department, the employees from those departments should be shown. And that's the issue. I can only get it to work with one of the departments selected.

I want to make sure that all employees from the selected departments are shown in the multiple select element, and also that, if one employee belongs to more than one department, he is only shown one time.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. I've tried to boil my code down, so this is the hardcoded version without getting stuff from the database.

Instead of posting the code here, I've made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kw5Km/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's add one more loop and if clause to the code. Additionally, we will use `obj.options[k].value` instead of `obj.value`:

```
for (k = 0; k < obj.options.length; k++) {                   // <-- add here
    if (obj.options[k].selected) {                           // <-- add here
        for (i = 0; i < selOptions.length; i++) {
            if (obj.options[k].value == selOptions[i][0]) {  // <-- change here
                for (j = 1; j < selOptions[i].length; j++) {
                    oSel2.options[oSel2.options.length] = new Option(
                        selOptions[i][j], selOptions[i][j], false, false);
                }
                i = selOptions.length;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Kw5Km/2/

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you so much. Is it possible to check if the same name appears more than once and then not add it to the second select if it does?

Comment: I updated the code by Vision to eliminate duplicate values. Demo http://jsfiddle.net/Kw5Km/3/

Comment: @pshoeg Here is another version that does the job: http://jsfiddle.net/Kw5Km/4/. Pay attention, I have slightly changed the `selOptions` variable.